# Auto submits the form when the page is loaded using React Hook

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, next.js, vercel

[image: Auto Submit Form Screencast by Chen Lay]

1. When the page being loaded, then I do want to **increment by 1** automatically.
2. When the page fully loaded, then I do want to submit the form automatically **without clicking the submit button**.

---

***The reason why I am doing this because I have plan to use with my own Cron Job. Thanks in advance.***

### Please guide me through how do I handle it?

```
import firebase from "@config/firebase.config";
import "firebase/firestore";

import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

// TODO: Main Form UI
const FormData = ({ justDummy }) => {
  // TODO: FORM REF
  const formRef = useRef(null);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // * This didn't work!
    // formRef.current.submit()
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <ScopedCssBaseline />
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={formRef} autoComplete="off">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={formRef} autoComplete="off">
          <Box sx={{ display: "flex", mt: 3 }}>
            <TextField
              onChange={() => console.log("")}
              value={id}
              type="number"
              placeholder="100"
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
              size="small"
              required
              color="primary"
              label="ID"
              disabled
            />
            <Box sx={{ mx: 0.5 }} />
            <TextField
              onChange={() => console.log("")}
              value={currentDate}
              placeholder="Current Date"
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
              size="small"
              color="primary"
              label="Date"
              disabled
            />
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
              variant="outlined"
              color="primary"
              disabled
            >
              Submit Data
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </form>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default FormData;
```

Comment: You can't emit user events unless the user actually triggered an event. What you can do is to send an ajax request with a formData object of your data in the useEffect hook.

Comment: And you have 2 forms.

Comment: I retrieve the ajax data from my api and populated into existing form then I implemented with Firebase to store that API data by submitting the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has been solved the issues of that. I removed the onSubmit function and replace with using React Ref then play around with Ajax.